# What is wrong with my query it keep inserting even after checking?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to set login time in and out when a user logs into the application

but even after doing check it keeps inserting new rows into database table caller login_hours

and also when i logout it rather than updating inserts another new row instead of updating the users last max id.

could someone please have a look at my query

for inserting if user does not exist on todays date

```
$tdate = new DateTime($utc);
            $tz = new DateTimeZone('America/New_York');         
            $tdate->setTimezone($tz);
            $now = $tdate->format('Y-m-d');
            $add = $tdate->format('Y-m-d h:i:s');
        
            
            $stmt = $db->prepare("
SELECT * 
  FROM login_hours 
 WHERE member_id = :member_id 
   AND username = :username 
   AND  time_in = :time_in
");
            $stmt->execute(array('member_id' => $_SESSION['member_id'], 'username' => $_GET['username'], 'time_in' => $now));
            $results = $stmt->rowCount();
            if($results == '0'){                
            $stmt = $db->prepare('
INSERT INTO login_hours (member_id, username, team, time_in, time_out) VALUES 
(:member_id, :username, :team, :time_in, :time_out)
 ') ;
            $stmt->execute(array(
                ':member_id' => $_SESSION['member_id'],
                 ':username' => $_SESSION['username'],
                 ':team' => $_SESSION['team'],
                 ':time_in' => $add,
                 ':time_out' => $add
         ));
            
    }
```

and in logout.php here is the query

```
$tdate = new DateTime($utc);
$tz = new DateTimeZone('America/New_York');         
$tdate->setTimezone($tz);
$add = $tdate->format('Y-m-d h:i:s');

$stmt = $db->prepare('
SELECT MAX(hours_id) 
  FROM login_hours 
 WHERE member_id = :member_id
') ;
$stmt->execute(array(':member_id' => $_SESSION['member_id']));
$rw = $stmt->fetch();           
$stmt = $db->prepare("
UPDATE login_hours 
   SET time_out = '".$add."' 
 WHERE hours_id = '".$rw[0]."'") ;
$stmt->execute();
```

can someone figure and help me out here please?

Thanks alot

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php `If the last SQL statement executed by the associated PDOStatement was a SELECT statement, some databases may return the number of rows returned by that statement. However, this behaviour is not guaranteed for all databases and should not be relied on for portable applications.` So see what `$results` is

Comment: the result keeps returning 0

Comment: This is not the correct way to prepare queries

Comment: @Strawberry please help me out here am also not pro still in learning stage